# Connecting multiple usb peripherals to a FPGA

Tags: usb, fpga, libusb, peripherals

I want to connect a USB peripherals to a FPGA. Basically FPGA should act like an USB host. Is there a FPGA board support a USB hub so that one could connect multiple(upto 4) USB peripherals at a time. 
I have a Digilent Nexys3 fpga which is based on Spartan 6. It supports only one USB device (keyboard or mouse). It doesn't support a hub. I have found Cypress host controllers, but I am not sure how to use it in a FPGA.

Comment: Generic USB host operations from an FPGA is pretty hard, I think. Instead, if you have any kind of USB host working now, I would duplicate it 4 times and add more USB ports to the device. The 4 host controllers would be completely independent, and only support 1 device each. Also, please post a link to the board you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a USB host controller inside your FPGA, such IP is not freely available, one alternative is to use a Zynq based (for Xilinx) or Cyclone V based (for Altera) board. Those have integrated USB controllers connected to their dual ARM core.

You can find more info about those at:

- [Altera Cyclone V](http://www.altera.com/devices/fpga/cyclone-v-fpgas/cyv-index.jsp?ln=devices_processor&l3=SoCs-Cyclone%20V%20%28SE,%20SX,%20ST%29)
- [Xilinx Zynq](http://www.xilinx.com/content/xilinx/en/products/silicon-devices/soc/zynq-7000.html)

You maybe able to use an external host controller but then you have to connect it to your FPGA and that is usually requires a lot of IOs and those modules are more expensive than buying a Zed board ($395) or Cyclone V board ($450).